# React and HowlerJS: Howler.ctx is null

Tags: reactjs, audiocontext, howler.js

I am trying to expose the AudioContext api in the global `Howler` and assign it to a variable, however I am unable to figure out how to get `Howler.ctx` to not be null.

```
const CTX = Howler.ctx ; // Howler.ctx is returning null
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `AudioContext` doesn't get setup in howler.js until a `Howl` is created. However, you can trick it into creating one by calling one of the following, which will in turn call the internal `setupAudioContext` method:

```
Howler.mute(false);
Howler.volume(1);
```

Comment: Also, import like this `import { Howler } from 'howler`